# Watson knowledge catalog: Edit existing rules

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-knowledge-catalog

I'm reviewing some of Watson Knowledge Catalog functionalities. For that I created a IBM Cloud lite account. I added a rule to a policie. I want to edit the rule, but when I try to use the option "edit rule"  the screen shows a message saying "this rule cannont be edited". I'm wondering if it is because it's a lite account. The documentation says you can not delete rules. So what can I do if I want to modify the existing rule to keep testing its functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

@Maria , Lite account has the ability to create/edit 1 rule at the maximum.
From UI you should be able to create/edit a rule